Micronaut application is not working from docker
please help to fix one micronaut issue: I am creating a native docker image (app must boot in 20ms), making port forwarding and it doesn't work - the app starts and nothing happens. I don't get what's wrong, chat gpt and gemini also.
Here is port setting via application.properties:
micronaut.server.port=${PORT}

here is part of docker run command
-p 8080:8080 --name ss-334 -e PORT=8080

you may ask why env variable and other bullshit?? well ask heroku why they assign ports like that.
Feel free to check the whole code: https://github.com/abondar24/TelegramBots/tree/master/Webhook/ChatAnalyzerBot

Listen, I understand that this can be frustrating, but can you please at least try to describe what the issue is?

Netty was breaking in docker - after swirching jetty it was starting fine
